# Can I use domain AND port in a routing group in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

Is there any way to bind routes to an port?
I am using Laravel 5.5

```
Route::domain('example.org:8080')->group(function() {... some routes ...})
Route::domain('example.org')->group(function() {... other routes ...})
```

I already tried to use a route pattern in the RouteServiceProvider.
But it only allows me to route by the complete domain.

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  ...
  public function boot()
  {
    // allow complete domains
    \Route::pattern('domain', '.+');
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think there is no way to do this in Laravel 5.x